# Check to see if NSMutableString does not contain a specific char

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

Is there a way to detect if an NSString does not contain a specific char (in this case it's a "-")? For example, if I have the NSString `@"-OU"` and the NSString `@"YOU"` is there a way to fire a UIAlert when the string is `@"YOU"` and not `@"-OU"`?

EDIT: By the way I'm trying to make this dynamic for any string. I currently have the following code and want to know if this can work:

```
  - (BOOL) isDone:(NSString *)str{

       unichar dash = '-';

    for(int i = 0; i < [str length]; i ++){
        if([str characterAtIndex:i] != dash){
            return YES;
        }

        else{
            return NO;
        }
    }

}
```

This code is currently throwing the following warning in xcode: "Control may reach end of non-void function".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your trying to test if the dash is in the word at all using your own build function i would do it this way

```
 - (BOOL) isDone:(NSString *)str{

       unichar dash = '-';

    for(int i = 0; i < [str length]; i ++){
        if([str characterAtIndex:i] == dash){
            return YES;
        }

    }
    return NO;

}
```

This way it will loop through entire string until it finds the dash, and will terminate as soon as it finds the dash, otherwise it will return NO once its done checking entire string.

Comment: ahhh good catch thank you! But actually I need to reverse the YES and the NO in your example (did for you).

Comment: please notice that, i changed the if statement from != to == to simplify things, but once again it all depends on the value ur looking to return.

Comment: check the below answer - using `rangeOfString`

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
NSString *yourString=@"-OU";  
if ([yourString rangeOfString:@"-"].location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"string does not contain -");
} else {
  NSLog(@"string contains -");
}
```

Comment: im not quite sure what your trying to do, are you just testing the if the first character is dash or not? if yes then why do the loop? your loop is terminated after the first character whether its true or false

Comment: I'm just trying to test if there is a dash in the word at all.